# c++ template code order parsing/CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Can someone give a hint how does compiler process expressions such as

```
class DerivedA: public ParentTemplateClass<DerivedA>{
}
```

For mee it looks like:

this boy's father is a "son" of this boy

I mean it's not obvious for me how "parsing" of the class DerivedA can be completed WITHOUT knowing the exactly "description" of parent class. Seems' it can not. So parent class must be processed before children, but in such situation parent depends on children..and I'm stuck there.

Yeah there some articles on the web which describe usage of such thing, e.g. an article about Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) but that's not some kind of standart or smth near. There must be clear behaviour description such as operations ordering isn't it?

ANSWERED:
Thnx to everyone. Yeah forward decl analogy seems legit for me to stop damaging my brain. Templates are still state of art for me cause of its hidden sublanguage nature and i cant just g++ -E :)

Comment: Think of it at this point as if it was a forward declaration.

Comment: I think of this as "The boy's father is defined in terms of this specific son."  I am not a fan of CRTP - I suspect it is over-used - but the interpretation of specific CRTP code is relatively straightforward.  The templates are always fully expanded before typed objects can be instantiated.

Comment: "The templates are always fully expanded before typed objects can be instantiated" yeah,seems legit. Some kind of blur effect for me is because temaplate instantiated during compilation and not preprocessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your code says `class DerivedA`, the symbol `DerviedA` is declared. At the point it can be used as a template parameter. C++ compilers do several passes on the code, so at that point in parsing the compiler will "believe" that your intention was correct and that it will eventually get the definition of that class (when it is about to instantiate the template, i.e. you actually use that type). If not, it will complain at that point. A similar thing happens if you used a forward declared class in a declaration but didn't provide a definition before using it.

Answer (score 3):

At the point at which the template is instantiated, `DerivedA` is *incomplete*; it has been *declared*, but not fully *defined*. Incomplete types can be used in various ways - for example, you can declare pointers or references to them, declare functions with them as return or parameter types, and a few other things. You can't create objects, inherit from them, access their members, or in general do anything that requires more information than just the class name.

As long as the class template only does these things, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think to understand how this could work, you need too understand more about C++ templates in general, than just the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.  Someone else can probably answer this better than me, but I know that C++ can't fully parse a template class definition by itself.  It instantiates the template each time it is used in the code.  If each class was in a separate include file, think of it like this:

```
#include "ParentTemplateClass.h" // C++ initially validates the template class definition's syntax.
#include "DerivedA.h" // First use of ParentTemplateClass -
                      //   at this point it becomes fully instantiated.
```

The C++ parser will initially validate the template's syntax when it sees the template definition.  Then, when the template is used as a base of DerivedA, the parsing continues and the template is fully instantiated. This is, of course, a simplified view of the parsing that the C++ compiler will do, and I'm sure the details vary by compiler.  See also http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation.